# How to assign a variable with CSV inline in JS

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to make a lightweight function to convert `csv` to `json` in `JS`.

To test the function I would like to save a `csv` file to a variable.

```
let csv = '"idCustomer","id1","id2","name1","name2"
"102188","1007","100788","Bobby","Some Company"
"102190","1049","100790","Alex","Some Company"
"102190","1033","100790","Paul","Some Company"
'

...

function csvJSON(csv){
  // conversion logic here
}
```

How can I set a a variable to `csv` inline with javascript?

Comment: you can use ` for multiline string.

Comment: Shouldn't you drop the double quotes though ?  Most csv files will look more like:
'102188,1007,100788,Bobby,Some Company'. Unless your function will only convert specific csv files...

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé I used an online JSON to CSV converter. It looks like CSV can be represented a few different ways in JS.

Comment: @AliD. single ticks seem to work for multi-line templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template literals to assign a string with line breaks to a variable.

e.g.

```
let csv = `"idCustomer","id1","id2","name1","name2"
"102188","1007","100788","Bobby","Some Company"
"102190","1049","100790","Alex","Some Company"
"102190","1033","100790","Paul","Some Company"`
```

Answer (score 0):

The newline character sequence is '\n'. A csv multiline string literal might look like:

```js
let csv = '"idCustomer","id1","id2","name1","name2"' + 
          '\n"102188","1007","100788","Bobby","Some Company"' +         
          '\n"102190","1049","100790","Alex","Some Company"' +
          '\n"102190","1033","100790","Paul","Some Company"'

console.log(csv);
```